# On sites with MathJax enabled, 2 $s in question title in sidebar mess up rendering

Tags: bug, mathjax

I encountered this problem while visiting Engineering, which has MathJax enabled.  Questions in the hot network questions that have dollar signs in them get rendered as if it was a MathJax encoding.

The actual question title was "Getting \$10,000, have \$16,000 balance on two credit cards - How to allocate payments?"

but it gets rendered as:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question? Just as you did in your post, the dollar signs should be escaped in the title. If this bothers you, suggest an edit to the post. You can even do this if you don't participate in that specific site.

Comment: That site (money.SE) doesn't have mathjax so it's unreasonable to expect them to escape the `$` but it is odd that the sidebar gets mathjaxed even when most of the questions there are on sites that don't have it enabled.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't? Well, then yeah, that's a bug.

Comment: @ratchetfreak - I'm migrating this to MSE so it will get more visibility.