# MathJax HNQ bug

Tags: bug, mathjax

There is currently a question from the personal finance stack in HNQ, titled:

```
Getting $10,000 and have $16,000 balance on two credit cards - How to allocate payments?
```

However, this renders like:

[image: mathjax fail]

This appears to be a consequence of [changing the MathJax delimiter](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/change-mathjax-delimiter), and odd to see since [MathJax titles don't show up in HNQ](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2844/questions-can-be-manually-removed-from-hnqs#2847)... is it possible to fix this without changing the MathJax delimiter again? (Have other MathJax-enabled stacks noticed this issue too?)

To be honest, I doubt this bug comes up often enough to warrant much attention, but being a software developer, I thought it would be good to at least document it :)

Comment: All he has to do is put a "\" in front of the first "$" to fix it.

Comment: @dcfyj Well, it's not a problem on the stack site it's posted on, and it's a bit silly to ask posters from other sites to accomodate our MathJax settings..

Comment: And this exact example was used in another recent question here: [On sites with MathJax enabled, 2 $s in question title in sidebar mess up rendering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284531).